# How to use SQL in Google Sheets for a table lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my data (the combination of `Lot No`. & `Date` is always unique):

[image]

Required result:

[image]

I used this:

`=QUERY(Production!A:G, "SELECT A,B, C, D, G WHERE A is NOT NULL label C 'NEW LOT NO.', D 'NEW LOT NO. DATE' ", 1)`

How can I add column `OLD ASSIGNED` in my query formula?

[Here is the SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WhybQBhWqe34JmNDkBy50bnS1GGqCbnl8Pi368BcEOU/edit?usp=sharing).

### Edit

I am seeking a solution **which uses only query ( or nested query)** and no other formulas like vlookup or filter or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=arrayformula(QUERY({Production!A:G,iferror(vlookup(Production!A1:A&"-"&Production!B1:B,{Production!C:C&"-"&Production!D:D,Production!G:G},2,false),)}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col8,Col3,Col4,Col7 WHERE Col1 is NOT NULL label Col3 'NEW LOT NO.', Col4 'NEW LOT NO. DATE', Col8 'OLD ASSIGNED'  ", 1))`

[image]

Or for `query` only:

```
=
query(
{
query({Production!A:G},"select Col7 where Col6 is not null order by Col4,Col3 label Col7 'OLD ASSIGNED'",1),
query({Production!A:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7 where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1 label Col3 'NEW LOT NO.', Col4 'NEW LOT NO. DATE' ",1)
},
"select Col2,Col3,Col1,Col4,Col5,Col6 order by Col5,Col3",1)
```

This uses `query` only so you'll need to choose a sort order for the results since Lot No. 277 appears in Col A and Col C with different date order.

If you want your original sort order, then it can work like this if you're prepared to use `sequence`:

```
=
query(
{
query({Production!A:G},"select Col7 where Col6 is not null order by Col4,Col3 label Col7 'OLD ASSIGNED'",1),
query({Production!A:G,sequence(counta(Production!A:A)+countblank(Production!A:A),1)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7,Col8 where Col1 is not null order by Col2,Col1 label Col3 'NEW LOT NO.', Col4 'NEW LOT NO. DATE' ",1)
},
"select Col2,Col3,Col1,Col4,Col5,Col6 order by Col7",1)
```

`sequence` is used to generate a sequence of row numbers (because `row()` would require the `arrayformula` - which you don't want). The range of number in the sequence is `counta(Production!A:A)+countblank(Production!A:A)` which is the number of rows in the Production sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm really curious if you could **please give me a solution which uses only query** ( or nested query) and no other formulas like vlookup or filter or anything, can you?

Comment: Please let me know if it's not possible?

Comment: I've added an alternative.

Comment: Thank you! I got three questions: **(1)** I replaced `'"&textjoin("|",true,query({if(Production!A2:A<>"",Production!A2:A&"-"&Production!B2:B,)},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0))&"'` from your formula with `'"&textjoin("|",true,if(Production!A2:A<>"",Production!A2:A&"-"&Production!B2:B,))&"'` and it's working, I just want to confirm if it's right?

Comment: **(2)** It's really weird but when I wrap textjoin to `=ARRAYFORMULA(query({if(Production!A2:A<>"",Production!A2:A&"-"&Production!B2:B,)}, "select Col1",0))` which is `=ARRAYFORMULA(textjoin("|",true,query({if(Production!A2:A<>"",Production!A2:A&"-"&Production!B2:B,)}, "select Col1",0)))` it says: "Query only takes 3 argument, but this is argument number 4", it only does not accept Query or header argument only accepts the Data. What exactly is happening?

Comment: **(3)** So it's impossible to just use SQL (and not any other sheets function like Arrayformula or TextJoin which were used) to get the the result I want?

Comment: I've updated the solution to use `query` only, but you'll need to specify a sort order unless you're happy to use `sequence` with it. Both options are there for you.

Comment: HEY! THIS WAS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED!  Your previous both query answers were wrong only vlookup one was right.

Comment: That's great. The issue with the previous two queries was probably how it was implemented in your sheet. My test sheet was OK, but glad you got what you wanted :-).